# two HTML forms submitting same php script, but i want 2nd form to run the code following it not the entire script

Tags: php, forms

i want to do somthing like:

1.php:

```
<html>
<form action=1.php method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data">
Choose a user name:<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Save and Proceed">
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
$name=$_POST['username'];
echo $name;
if($name=='azra')
{
    ?>
    <html>
<form method="POST" action="1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></br>
enter age:</font> <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit" value="done">
</form>
</html>
<?php
f( isset($_POST['age']))
{
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    echo $age;
    if($age==25)
    {
        echo "your age is ". $age;
        echo"you are eligible";
    }
}   
}   


}
?>
```

After the second form is submitted i do not want the script 1.php to run from the start but i want it to run the code following the form which is echoing the age only.
i do not want to go putting the later code in second script and accessing the variable of first script through making them session variables.please help. thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition to this

```
if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Save and Proceed')) {
}
```

Comment: ok and should add ($_POST['submit'] == 'done') on the second part of the script?

Comment: its not working this way too, should it be button value where the query should be checked ?

Comment: i am checking on button value its still not working m posting the rectified code, i meant to ask should the query be on button name instead of value? should i add button name field too?

Comment: Do one thing change your first button to this                                                                                                                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and Proceed">

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i changed:

```
<html>
<form method="POST" action="2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></br>
Choose a user name:</font> <input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Save and Proceed">
</form>
</html>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Save and Proceed'))
{
$name=$_POST['username'];
echo $name;
if($name=='azra')
{
    ?>
    <html>
<form method="POST" action="2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></br>
enter age:</font> <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit" value="done">
</form>
</html>
<?php
if( isset($_POST['age']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'done'))
{
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    echo $age;
    if($age==25)
    {
        echo "your name is" .$name;
        echo "your age is ". $age;
        echo"you are eligible";
    }
}

}       

}
?>
```

Comment: Change your first button to this <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and Proceed">

Comment: ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit') ?? the check should be on button name or value?

Comment: Check should be on value  : ($_POST['submit'] == 'Save and Proceed')

Comment: still code following the 2nd form is getting skipped